# Content-Type is missing with Spring GET/POST method

Tags: java, spring

I am new to `Spring` and I am trying to do the basic `GET` and `POST` method.

This is how I am trying to do the methods:

```
@RestController
public class DeskController {

    @Autowired
    private DeskDao dao;

    @GetMapping("desks")
    public List<Desk> getDesks() {
        System.out.println(dao.findById(1L));
        return dao.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("desks")
    public Desk save(@RequestBody @Valid Desk desk) {
        Desk deskObj = dao.save(desk);
        System.out.println(deskObj);
        return deskObj;
    }
```

When I am calling the `POST` method like this I get the `pring` with the actual object that I had called it with so it is working fine, but I also get this error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Content-Type is missing
```

And when trying to call `GET` it tells me that:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I am aware that I have not included the whole code, but I will add what is needed to resolve this error since there are a lot of classes.

My questions are, what do I do against the first `error` and why is `GET` method not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to change :

1. Use a `/` to indicate that for this path you will perform an
   operation. For eg : (`/desks`)
2. Use the annotation `@Consumes` to
   indicate that this method accepts the payload in particular format. For eg : `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotated over your `save()` method.

Comment: What do I need to impor to use `@Consumes`? Because I tried importing `javax.ws.rs` and it said that `Attribute value must be constant`. Also is `@Consumes` only for `POST` and `@Produces` for `GET` ?

Comment: 1. `import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;` 2. The `@GET` operation cannot consume an entity. 3. You need to specify a `MediaType` in order for `@Consumes` to work.

Comment: What would the `MediaType` be in this situation?

Comment: Depends, in what format are you posting data? It could be in the form of json, text, xml, etc.

Comment: Anyways I'm guessing `@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json")` does the same thing but it does not fix the `GET` error.. You also mentioned adding `/` in front of `desks` but I have that added elsewhere.